# Is there a way to guard the creation of covergroup bins

Tags: verilog, code-coverage, system-verilog, hdl, test-bench

is there a way to guard the creation of the an explicitly named bin as seen here

```
coverpoints_bins: coverpoint signal_a
bins a1 = {1};
bins a2 = {2};
bins a4 = {4}; <--- create bin a4 only if parameter "CREATE_A4 is 1"
```

for example something like this :

```
coverpoints_bins: coverpoint signal_a
bins a1 = {1};
bins a2 = {2};
bins a4 = {4} create_iff(CREATE_A4 == 1);
```

note: create_iff is just some pseudocode function to guard against the creation of bins unless the condition is true

because to my knowledge the `iff` condition does not guard against the creation of the bins but `iff` only serves to guard against a bin hit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `with` clause to select bins

```
bins a4 = {4} with (CREATE_A4 == 1);
```

This will likely generate a warning message saying you have an empty bin set. Another way of doing this is using a bin set array.

```
int my_bins[];
...
if (CREATE_A4 == 1) // execute this before constructing the covergroup
   my_bins = {1,2,4};
else
   my_bins = {1,2};

...
coverpoints_bins: coverpoint signal_a
bins a[] = my_bins;
```